# Error executing script in powershell WSUS GetUpdate()

Tags: powershell

I executed a Powershell script, but I got an error

#### Script

```
[datetime]$dataIni = "2017/01/01" 
[datetime]$dataFim = "2017/01/20"

$serverWsus = "server1"

[void]
$wsus =[Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy]::getUpdateServer($serverWsus,$False,8530)

Write-Progress -Activity 'Getting updates...' -PercentComplete 0

$updatesneeded = $wsus.GetUpdate() | ? {($_.CreationDate -gt 
[datetime]$dateFirst -and 
$_.CreationDate -lt [datetime]$dateLast) -and 
($_.Title -notmatch "Itanium" -and 
$_.Title -match "Windows Server 2008 x64" -and  
$_.UpdateClassificationTitle -eq "Security Updates")} 

$i = 0
$total = $updatesneeded.Count
foreach ($update in $updatesneeded) 
{ 
 Write-Progress -Activity 'Approving updates...' -Status "%Complete" -
 PercentComplete (($i/$total) * 100)
 Approve-WsusUpdate -Update $update -Action Install -TargetGroupName 'enviroment'
 $i++
 }
 Write-Host "Updates approved: $total" -ForegroundColor Yellow
```

#### Error

```
Cannot find an overload for "GetUpdate" and the argument count: "0".
```

At line:11 char:1
+ $updatesneeded = $wsus.GetUpdate() | ? {($_.CreationDate -gt [datetime]$dateFirs ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Approve-WsusUpdate : Cannot bind parameter 'Update'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.BaseApi.Update" value of type "Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.BaseApi.Update" 
to type "Microsoft.UpdateServices.Commands.WsusUpdate".
At line:22 char:32
+     Approve-WsusUpdate -Update $update -Action Install -TargetGroupName 'enviroment'
+                                ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Approve-WsusUpdate], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.UpdateServices.Commands.ApproveWsusUpdateCommand

Comment: A typo? `GetUpdate(UpdateRevisionId)` Gets the specified update. `GetUpdates()` Gets a collection of the latest revision of each update.

Comment: Couple other recommendations: set `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` early so that you don't cascade into secondary errors that can confuse the issue.  Also, use an UpdateScope with `GetUpdates()` so that the filtering is done by SQL rather than retrieving everything and then filtering on the pipeline.  That will be *MUCH* faster. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.updateservices.administration.updatescope_members(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Even using `Get-WsusUpdate -Classification Security -Status Needed` would be a big improvement without the scope.   That way you don't download and approve updates that computers don't need.  (This requires that the computers have scanned already and reported status.)

Comment: Hi Matthew, how are you? Please do you can help me with my script include an Update Scope?